# How to use json_annotation with a Dart Extended ListBase class

Tags: dart, angular-dart

So I have a @JsonSerializable class that's doing the job without an issue.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class BaseValue {
  String id;
  var value;
  DateTime valueDate;

  BaseValue({
    this.id,
    this.value,
    this.valueDate
  });
  factory BaseValue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BaseValueFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BaseValueToJson(this);
}
```

No I want to have the same fromJson toJson enabled for an extended ListBase class but can't find how to implement this.

```
class BaseValues<BaseValue> extends ListBase<BaseValue> {
  final List<BaseValue> l = [];
  BaseValues();

  void set length(newLength) => l.length = newLength;
  int get length => l.length;
  BaseValue operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, BaseValue value) => l[index] = value;
}
```

Maybe I need to use something else instead of ListBase.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Why not just use List<BaseValue> ?

Comment: `json_serializable` will only ever decode to a native `List`, not a custom list implementation. What is the use case for not using a native list?

Comment: `json_serializable` can decode a non-native `List`, but not out of the box. You need to implement custom conversion for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's not super easy. You need to create a custom [TypeHelper](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/json_serializable/latest/type_helper/TypeHelper-class.html) to support your class.

Then, if you want to use `pub run build_runner...` you'll need to create a custom builder that instantiates an instance of [JsonSerializableGenerator](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/json_serializable/latest/json_serializable/JsonSerializableGenerator-class.html) and include an instance of your `TypeHelper`.

There is a pending commit that will give you some more freedom here - https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/commit/4f19d468bf05eed3e4a8ebc27244fc3b8d411dc9 – but you'll still have to handle the possible generic type args of `BaseValues`.